# How to pass authorization header in $.post() method using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery, jquery-post

I want to pass Authorization header while POSTing data to server.
I tried

```
$.ajax({
   url : <ServiceURL>,
   data : JSON.stringify(JSonData),
   type : 'POST',
   contentType : "text/html",
   dataType : 'json',
   success : function(Result) {
   },
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', <Authorization Header Value>);
   },
   error: function (RcvData, error) {
      console.log(RcvData);
   }
});
```

But REST service returns error (error code : 500). The same service was working fine with $.post() before adding authorization.
could anyone tell me "How to pass authorization header in $.post()??"

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
 contentType: 'application/json',
```

You may have gotten `data` and `contentType` mixed up.

- `contentType` is the `Content-type` header you send.
- `data` changes how jQuery treats the data you receive.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery $.ajax() method accepts a `headers` value in the settings object.

So:

```
$.ajax({
    // url, data, etc...
    headers: {
        "Authorization" :"Basic " + myBase64variable,
        "Content-Type" :"application/json"
    }
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

PS: Seems you can also pass in a new settings object in the beforeSend parameter. I didn't know this, so thanks for asking this question :)